# Line dimensions in Sketch.app do not match display and output

Tags: sketch-app

I have a rectangle in Sketch that is 100px height. 
I drew a line at 100px but it shows as 99.01px yet matches height of the rectangle?

Comment: Welcome keano! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site or their forums. We are confident you will find answers. If you want to know more about GD.SE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Lines in Sketch have end caps, extending them 0.5px on each end.

[image]

> I drew a line at 100px but it shows as 99.01px yet matches height of the rectangle?

99px + 0.5px cap on one end + 0.5px cap on the other end = 100px.
(I’m not sure where the 0.01px comes from.)

Comment: what is the point of X1 and X2? It makes it more complicated

Comment: @keano X1 and Y1 are the coordinates for the starting point, while X2 and Y2 are the coordinates for the end point. They are off, by half a pixel to ensure the line is exactly one pixel wide (the line is drawn from its center).

Answer (score 1):

As Marc noted, there is that bizarre end cap behavior. Unfortunately, that doesn't explain the oddness you're seeing. I'm using the beta release now (version 3.3.1) and this problem persists.

Bottom line:

## Sketch.app has a bug with line coordinates

There, I said it. But I don't totally blame them. A line (width or height, one dimension, kinda) is an awkward thing to snap to a pixel grid (width and height, two dimensions). So I understand how Bohemian ended up in this predicament. Look at the X2 value below — it's just dumb.

[image: Crazy line coordinates in Sketch]

## But Sketch is not alone

Illustrator had (has?) unpleasantness with snapping lines to a grid too. I haven't used it for UI in a while (Sketch took the torch), but Illustrator would always give me lines sitting between pixels. It made a worse mistake and aligned the *points* of the line to the grid. Unless the line weight was an even number, this would result in half pixel fogginess. No good.

## The work around

Both Sketch and Illustrator know how to put a rectangle on a pixel grid (2D on 2D action). Draw a rectangle to the dims of your line (eg 1px high × 300px wide) and viola! Perfect, comprehensible coordinates.

[image: Sensible rectangle coordinates in Sketch]

I found this to be a necessity in Illustrator to avoid blurry lines. In Sketch, it's not *required* since the display and export are correct. This is purely for the obsessives among us that are always checking dims out of habit.